# Software Recommendations Stack Exchange - Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

We want to congratulate and thank everyone that helped this site and community grow healthily into what they are today!

If you can find your name among the top 72 users in the first two pages [here](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), we have a surprise for you! We want to send you a token of our appreciation for being among the most prolific users in this community! As such, we're sending you a little box, inside which you'll find:

[image: ![A T-SHIRT!]

T-SHIRTS!!!!!!!

[image: ![STICKERS!]

STICKERS!!!!!!!

I don't know why they have floppy disks with very old Microsoft Windows software on them, but apparently they're a good place to put a sticker.

I'll be reaching out to you shortly with a link to a form: be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so! You'll have two weeks to do it, after which I'll close the form and take care of sending all of the swag your way! It should take from 6 to 8 weeks for the package to be delivered to you!

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such!

Thanks to all of you for making this site great!

**Update 10/18/2016:** We're sorry for the delay. We did send quite a few swag runs to our warehouse at about the same time, so they are slightly backlogged. As far as I know, this run is still in the process of having the product finalized before mass printing and has not been shipped. I will let you all know when I hear anything further.

Comment: Awesome! Oops - I have 2 accounts and both of them are listed. I guess I can't be awarded twice, so let's give away one set to the first person on page 3.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Absolutely. I was already planning to pull 1 extra person to make up for that Tim Post guy stealing one of the spots. Pffft. *That* guy.

Comment: 7 weeks ... I'm so excited ... It could arrive every day ...

Comment: [11 weeks](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=25&m1=07&y1=2016&d2=9&m2=10&y2=2016) ... Should I be worried?! :/

Comment: Did someone receive it already?

Comment: Any update on this? Almost half a year is passed and I've not received my swag yet x)

Comment: I too neither received it yet.

Comment: Looks like you don't have to be in the "top 72" of users ... at least I'm not, but today I found a similar package in my mail, shipped all the way to the land of beer, chocolats and fries ... aka BE. ***Merci***! PS: for those who are not so good in French: ***thank you***!

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens You *were* half a year ago when the top 72 was selected for swag. You just aren't anymore. But that doesn't matter.

Comment: @animuson : aha, that's the explanation ... Just to be sure the rules won't change, and even "today" that doesn't matter, I might soon try to get (about) +60 points, to avoid some other SE requests arrives to ship it back ... stay tuned ...

Comment: Thanks for the gesture, but I would not use it, so you can give it to someone else. **However** (and that's the reason I'm commenting here on 6 Feb 2017) I have never seen any mail with a link to a form. Maybe caught in a spam trap, maybe something wrong in your administration. I.e. something to watch out for next time.

Comment: Still waiting ...

Answer (score 7):

Yay! Mine arrived today. Thanks a lot!! :D

[image]

Comment: Awesome! I hadn't been informed these ever shipped out. Good to know. *thumbs up*

Comment: [Mine too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2onW.jpg) The shirt is a great fabric type.

Comment: @Undo yes, it is much nicer than my ask Ubuntu shirt.

Comment: Mine came this morning too.  The packaging survived being found by the dog.

Comment: Also in Scotland ... brightened a dark January day!

Comment: Good mine too. Yaay

Comment: Mine did not arrive yet. :-(

Comment: Yesterday, the package was in my post box. :-) :-) :-) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you very much.  That's thoughtful.

I have a sufficient amount of clothing, and would prefer to donate mine to someone more needy who perhaps does not have a clean shirt to wear.

Would you be willing to ship my t-shirt to a homeless shelter instead of sending it to me?  That would make me happy. :-)

Comment: Hm, I think it would be more meaningful if you delivered it to a local shelter rather than us shipping it to some random shelter. Of course, you are always free to just enter the address for a local shelter so that it gets delivered directly to them (although I wouldn't personally advise it without at least getting their permission to do so first).

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much animuson & Stack Exchange. I don't have any stickers on my laptop but I think I might make an exception:).

---

My shirt and stickers came as well, thank you so much StackExchange:)

Answer (score 1):

Shirt will be given to someone, most likely anyone looking in need of it but stickers I wanna put up in nice places

I bought my self a wooden case PC, can't wait to receive sticker and  put it on :)

Answer (score 0):

Got mine a couple of days ago - brilliant! Thank you very much! I think I was one of the lower rep users to just qualify for the merch, but it's greatly appreciated! :)

[image: Software recommendations tshirt modelled by self]

Answer (score 0):

Mine has now arrived, (all the way in Australia).
I'm pretty happy about this,
the fabric is loverly.
And it means a bit, since this was the first site I committed to on Area51, and I put in a fair bit when it was starting up as part of my committment (and then when we reached public beta and were well established more or less dropped off.)

One suggestion for future shirts of this type,
would be the have the StackExchange name and logo on it as well,
because that is a much better known brand than any individual site (except the big 3).
And it gives context to the shirt, that just saying "Software Recommendations" does not.