# Congratulations to Thomas Weller!

Tags: discussion

Please join me in congratulating community member [Thomas Weller](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/1935/thomas-weller) in being the newest member to join our 10,000 reputation point club.  He will now enjoy all the amazing international perks that go along with being in that exclusive club!

I'm happy to reveal that my upvote on [this quality question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/87904/switching-profiles-to-do-not-disturb-for-multiple-tools) tipped him over the top!

Our other community members in good standing of this exciting and prestigious club:

- Franck Dernoncourt
- Steve Barnes
- Nicolas Raoul
- Izzy

Club benefits include:

- Unlimited extra-large Slurpee cups at all 7-11's internationally, with purchase of equal number of extra-large Slurpees
- Free entry into all Disney theme parks, as long as you can convince them you are the real R2D2
- Unlimited water refills at all the finest McDonald's dining establishments
- Your choice of Wonder Woman's invisible jet or Harry Potter's invisible cloak, delivered directly to your home
- Free doughnuts at all local doughnut shops... just tell them I sent you!

*Offers void where prohibited by law or common sense.*

Answer (score 5):

Thank you very much for noticing and providing all the new benefits.

I love the community over here. It's more helpful and less toxic than Stack Overflow, just IMHO.

Why am I so keen on knowing tools? This goes back to 2004, when I just finished high school. We didn't learn anything about tools at high school. Just `vi` and `javac`, if you call those "tools".

At my first company, I had a colleague there, Thorsten Schleinzer. Whenever I had a problem, I went to him. And he *always* knew a cool tool that would help me solve my problems, automate my work, reduce mistakes or teach me things. If he didn't know a tool, he would simply write it himself. Those tools made me so productive!

I was a bit worried when he switched companies. That definitely changed in 2014 when I became aware of Software Recommendations. Since then, I like asking for new tools and getting recommendations from all of you and hopefully helping out some other people with tools which I know helped me. It's that give and take which motivates me.

I still wear the [SR T-Shirt](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2579/software-recommendations-stack-exchange-top-user-swag) every third week or so. Hard to believe that it survived for more than 6 years. Awesome!

Everybody, please keep up the good work. Your posts have been and will be valuable to someone.

Comment: You're most welcome.  I always look forward to your posts, and I learn quite a bit from them.  Plus, they set great examples for everybody of how to write quality questions and answers.  I particularly admire that you've written about the same number of questions and answers.  That's quite impressive!

Comment: Well done Thomas! :-)

Comment: "more helpful and less toxic than Stack Overflow, just IMHO." +1, and also compared to several other SE sites.  and +1 about high school failing to teach many important topics.